# question about mnesia distribution

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

I have two nodes running mnesia. I created schema and some tables on *node 1*, and used `mnesia:add_table_copy` on *node 2* to copy the tables from node 1 to *node 2*.

Everything works well until I call `q()` on *node 1* and then `q()` on *node 2*. I found that when I start *node 1* again, `mnesia:wait_for_tables([sometable], infinity)` won't return. It will only return when I start *node 2* again.

Is there a way to fix this? This is a problem because I won't be able to start *node 1* again if *node 2* is down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this discussion](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/About-mnesia-in-multi-nodes-td2119396.html) a situation similar to the one you're facing is presented.

Reading from that source:

> At startup Mnesia tries to connect
>   with the other nodes and if that
>   suceeds it  loads its tables from
>   them. If the other nodes are down, it
>   looks for  mnesia_down  marks in its
>   local transaction log in order to
>   determine if it has a consistent 
>   replica or not of its tables. The node
>   that was shutdown last has
>   mnesia_down's  from all the other
>   nodes. This means that it safely can
>   load its tables. If some  of the other
>   nodes where started first (as in your
>   case) Mnesia will  wait indefinitely 
>   for another node to connect in order
>   to load its tables

You're shutting down node 1 first, so it doesn't have the `mnesia_down` from the other node. What happens if you reverse the shutting down order?

Also, it should be possible to force the table loading via the [force_load_table/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#force_load_table-1) function:

```
force_load_table(Tab) -> yes | ErrorDescription
```

> The Mnesia algorithm for table load
>   might lead to a situation where a
>   table cannot be loaded. This situation
>   occurs when a node is started and
>   Mnesia concludes, or suspects, that
>   another copy of the table was active
>   after this local copy became inactive
>   due to a system crash.
>
> If this situation is not acceptable,
>   this function can be used to override
>   the strategy of the Mnesia table load
>   algorithm. This could lead to a
>   situation where some transaction
>   effects are lost with a inconsistent
>   database as result, but for some
>   applications high availability is more
>   important than consistent data.

Comment: thanks, that partly solves my problem. but supposed i started node 1 using mnesia:force_load_table/1, and after that i found node 2 is up again, is there a way to merge the changes? mnesia:set_master_node seems to work during startup, but cannot be used to force a "fetch" from the master node.