# force load mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

As I understand we can use force_load_table/1 to force loading table in mnesia.

Could you show an example of usage this function?

Comment: I dont have any code around, but here you can find some help http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap3.html

Answer (score 0):

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253981/erlang-question-about-mnesia-distribution) we've discussed a possible use of the `mnesia:force_load_table/1` function, in the case of two Erlang nodes.

If you're looking for some code snippet containing a call to the function, it's probably a good idea to tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do and why you're thinking about using exactly that function.